# How to fine tune n_components parameter in UMAP?

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, python-3.x

I am using UMAP for clustering. However I can't find any information about methods to fine tune n_components parameter (which is very important). As good as I understand I can't use explained variance as for PCA. So what are alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There is a UMAP parameter called n_component, which is the dimension in output (1D, 2D, etc.).
https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameters.html#n-components

UMAP is not like PCA in terms of n_components: In fact, all the initial dimensions (=initial data having m features) are projected to a lower-dimensional space (=n components).

The UMAP axes don't have the same meaning as the PCA axes: UMAP represents a relative space of probabilities, whereas PCA axes represent the main features' abundance of variation.

As a consequence, you just have to choose n_components based on data complexity and volume.

In most cases, n_components = 2 is the best option because it is easier to read a 2D map than a 1D or 3D map or more. Very simple cases with few clusters would be better with n_components = 1. In complex cases with many features, n_components = 3 or more might be better.

Note that for output with n_components >=3, you can extract 2D views from it to see clusters from different angles.

Here is a cool website explaining UMAP interactively: https://pair-code.github.io/understanding-umap/